# Hiredis fails when deploying with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, capistrano, hiredis, redis-rails

When trying to deploy an app with **ruby 2.2.0** and **rails 4.2.0** with gems **redis v3.0.1** and **hiredis v0.4.5** task which responsible for interactions with **redis** server fails with the following error:

```
.....ruby/2.2.0/gems/hiredis-0.4.5/lib/hiredis/ext/hiredis_ext.so: undefined symbol: rb_thread_select
cap aborted!
```

Does anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rb_thread_select has been deprecated and removed from trunk so you will need to use a current version of hiredis which has removed the rb_thread_select dependency.